# Telerik report parameters datetime not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, telerik, reporting

I made a report, I tested the query in SQL with the parameters and it's working, however, with teleriks reports 2013 something is wrong, it looks like is not working, I followed this steps in the wizard.

[image]
SQL query

[image]
Report Parameters Default

[image]
Results

[image]
Graph Result

[image]
Report Parameters

Howerver, when I change the dates, and click on preview, it always gives me the same results.

The questions would be how can I make this paremeters work, and what's wrong with all I did?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the Configure Datasource wizard step, you are hard-coding the values. You need to set them to the parameter values there. Normally there is a drop-down with the available parameters or you can use the Edit Expression dialog.

Off the top of my head, it should look something like:

> = Parameters.DESDE.Value
>
> = Parameters.HASTA.Value

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to filter using a range of dates with different fields in the SQL Where clause.

Could you try changing the where clause for one of the above to check if it changes the displayed results?

```
WHERE A.DateClientRequest >= @DESDE
AND A.DateClientRequest <= @HASTA
```

OR

```
WHERE A.DateRegister >= @DESDE
AND A.DateRegister <= @HASTA
```

By the way I think you can improve this where clause using the BETWEEN clause.

Comment: It has to be as I did in the original query